# Spark Kubernetes Error : Pod Already Exists

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

When i try to submit my app through spark-submit i get the following error:
Please help me resolve the problem

***Error:***

```
pod name: newdriver
         namespace: default
         labels: spark-app-selector -> spark-a17960c79886423383797eaa77f9f706, spark-role -> driver
         pod uid: 0afa41ae-4e4c-47be-86a3-1ef77739506c
         creation time: 2020-05-06T14:11:29Z
         service account name: spark
         volumes: spark-local-dir-1, spark-conf-volume, spark-token-tks2g
         node name: minikube
         start time: 2020-05-06T14:11:29Z
         phase: Running
         container status:
                 container name: spark-kubernetes-driver
                 container image: spark-py:v3.0
                 container state: running
                 container started at: 2020-05-06T14:11:31Z
Exception in thread "main" io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: https://172.17.0.2:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods. Message: pods "newtrydriver" already exists. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=409, details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null, kind=pods, name=newtrydriver, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=pods "newtrydriver" already exists, metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=AlreadyExists, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:510)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.assertResponseCode(OperationSupport.java:449)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:413)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:372)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleCreate(OperationSupport.java:241)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:819)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.create(BaseOperation.java:334)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.create(BaseOperation.java:330)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client.$anonfun$run$2(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client.$anonfun$run$2$adapted(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:129)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2539)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:129)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.$anonfun$run$4(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.$anonfun$run$4$adapted(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2539)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.start(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
20/05/06 14:11:34 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/05/06 14:11:34 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-b7ea9c80-6040-460a-ba43-5c6e656d3039
```

- Configuration for Submitting the job to k8s

  ./spark-submit 
          --master k8s://https://172.17.0.2:8443 
          --deploy-mode cluster 
          --conf spark.executor.instances=3 
          --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark-py:v3.0 
          --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark 
          --name newtry 
          --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=newdriver 
          local:///opt/spark/examples/src/main/python/spark-submit-old.py
- Running spark on k8s in Cluster Mode
- No other Pod with the name newdriver running on my minikube

Comment: this error is obvious because you did have a pod by that name already at Minikube. Try by adding a `restartPolicy: Never`

Comment: @Gupta Thanks for the reply, No i don't have any pod of the same name which i am trying to create here and can you please let me know how to add restartPolicy i am new to spark and kubernetes. I just checked  the spark official documentation there is no such thing like restartPolicy which can be added to the kubernetes client.

Comment: can you share your manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is a Pod named `newdriver` in namespace `default` by running `kubectl get pods --namespace default --show-all`. You probably already have `Terminated` or `Completed` Spark Driver Pod with this name left from the previous runs. If so, delete it by running `kubectl delete pod newdriver --namespace default` and then try to launch new Spark job again.

Comment: I checked there is no pod of such name in default `namespace` and i did delete pod new driver but no success.

Comment: And what about `newtrydriver` ? Basically the idea is that you should have it, otherwise the exception message is meaningless and more debug information is required.